# Rancher connect to kubernetes instead of start kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Rancher is designed (as best as I can tell) to own and run a kubernetes cluster. Rancher does provide a configuration so that kubectl can interact w/ the kubernetes cluster. Rancher seems like a nice tool. But as far as I can tell, there is no way to connect to an existing kubernetes cluster. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a service that can connect to an existing k8s cluster(s) then try Containership. You can use Kubectl and/or the Containership UI to manage you workloads, config maps, etc on multiple clusters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer on the rancher forums

> There is not, most of the value we can add at the moment is around configuring, managing, and controlling access to the installation we setup.

https://forums.rancher.com/t/rancher-connect-to-kubernetes-instead-of-start-kubernetes/3209